# Which type of recombination mechanism happens in Silicon?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

As far as I understood, in Silicon even though is an indirect semiconductor it also has direct recombination but with a low probability. This happens because its main recombination mechanism is indirect recombination, aided with traps and defects. I thought the first time that the recombination mechanism was the Auger recombination, but this type of recombination only happens for high carrier densities (highly doped materials). Am I right about this, please somebody confirms or correct any of these assumptions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Recombination requires momentum and energy conservation. But since the momentum carried away by a photon in radiative recombination is small compared to those of the recombining electron and hole, one often considers that the two momenta shoudl be equal, which means that the initial and the final electron states should be at the same k-point in Brillouin zone. At reasonable temperatures all electrons are at the minima of the conduction band and all the holes are at the maximum of the valence band - thus, if these two do not coincide, the recombination with conservation of momentum is not likely to happen.

The conservation of momentum can be however apended by interaction with impurities, other electrons, phonons, etc. Thus, e.g., in highly doped semiconductors, electron may recombine with a hole while transferring extra momentum to an impurity site (or a lattice imperfection). Note that in terms of the perturbation theory it si a higher order process, infolving product of the matrix elements corresponding to scattering from an impurity and radiative recombination.